# Dynamic Initialization

Tags: c++

C++03 Standard *[basic.start.init] point 3* states:

> It is implementation-defined whether or not the dynamic
>   initialization (8.5, 9.4, 12.1, 12.6.1) of an object of namespace
>   scope is done before the first statement of main. If the
>   initialization is deferred to some point in time after the first
>   statement of main, it shall occur before the first use of any
>   function or object defined in the same translation unit as the
>   object to be initialized.

Microsoft Compilers, according to [Additional Startup Considerations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0e519f64%28v=vs.80%29), perform the initialization prior to `main()`.

I have been unable to obtain documentation stating the behaviour for GNU and Sun Forte compilers.

Can anyone:

1. Point me in the direction of documentation that describes the behaviour of the GNU and Forte compilers with respect to dynamic initialization (I have checked the GCC manual and found nothing relating to dynamic initialization).
2. Comment on the thread-safety of deferred dynamic initialization (if two threads attempt to invoke a function from the same translation unit that contains a non-local object).

---

FWIW, I observed the behaviour of GNU's g++ and SUN's CC and both performed the initalization prior to main though I don't accept this as a definitive answer. (*I can post the very simple code I used to observe if anyone is interested but I felt the question is long enough*)

Comment: There is an exception for dynamic libraries, where the initialization is likely perform at load time, even if this is after the first statement of `main()`.

Comment: This is quite an interesting question: If you say `std::ostream & o = (std::cout << "Hello\n"); int main() { std::cout <<"World\n"; }`, in which order do the lines get printed?

Comment: @KerrekSB In that case, there's no ambiguity, since the initialization must occur before the first function in the translation unit is called.

Comment: @JamesKanze: is that guaranteed? Where? I got myself confused about that recently.

Comment: @KerrekSB: In the quote in the question. Applying to you code, `o` must be initialized before any function in this translation unit is called, that is before `main` is called.

Comment: @ybungalobill: Oh, OK. So what if I put the two lines in separate TUs?

Comment: @KerrekSB: then the other translation unit may be thrown away completely. Since there is nothing used in the translation unit where `o` is defined, it may be deferred indefinitely, therefore it may never get initialized, therefore the linker can optimized it away.

Comment: @ybungalobill But no compiler does.  And no compiler would dare do so, since it would break too much code.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Heh? All sane linkers I know do unreferenced translation units removal. Even if it changes the behavior (since the initialization may have side effects). And they are allowed to do so exactly by this section of the standard. You are welcome to try it yourself.

Comment: @ybungalobill I don't know what platforms you work on then.  VC++ doesn't do it, nor does the Linux linker, nor the Solaris linker, nor the linker on AIX or HP-UX.  I've regularly written code which depended on static initializers being called to register the functionality, with, in some cases, no non-static data in the translation unit at all, and it's always worked.  It's also a standard idiom, widely described.

Comment: @ybungalobill: I once had to use `--whole-archive` to make the linker include a whole `.a` library of self-registering classes and execute global constructors -- but it did run all of them. And I have a feeling that that's a pretty common pattern. That's why I got worried lately!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definitive answer is that all compilers do static initialization
before `main`, *unless* the objects are in a DLL which is loaded later.
In practice, it's (almost) impossible to meet the requirements in the
text you cite otherwise.  (Think of what happens if there is a cycle.)