# When static global variable are created in C++

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I know that global variables are created in declaration order for same compilation unit and creation order is not defined between multiple compilation units.

I've read some time ago that global variables are created before any code from the compilation unit where they are defined is called. Is this defined by the standard?

Example:

file1.cpp

```
int f1v1 = f1_1();
int f1v2 = f1_2();

void f1(){...}

int f1_1(){...}
int f1_2(){...}
```

file2.cpp

```
static int f2v1 = f2_1();
static int f2v2 = f2_2();

int f2_1(){...}
int f2_2(){...}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"

int main()
{
    f1();

    return 0;
}
```

Is in this case guaranteed by the standard that `f1_1()` is called before `f1_2()` and before `f1()`? Is guaranteed by the standard that `f2_1()` and `f2_2()` are called at all as no function defined in file2.cpp is called and `f2v1` and `f2v2` are not visible outside file2.cpp?

EDIT:

Is the behavior specified by the standard when file1.cpp is compiled in lib1 and file2.cpp is compiled in lib2?

Comment: You may find this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321401/dynamic-initialization useful

Comment: Note: whether `static` or only effects the *linkage* of the variable, its initialization is identical.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I wanted to make it clear the variables are not used (accessed from other place)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [basic.start.init]:

`f1_1()` is guaranteed to execute before `f1_2()` (para.2: "Variables with ordered initialization defined within a single translation unit shall be initialized in the order of their definitions in the translation unit.").

Both are guaranteed to execute before `f1()` (para.4: "If the initialization is deferred to some point in time after the first statement of main, it shall occur before the first odr-use (3.2) of any function or variable defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized.").

About `f2_1()` and `f2_2()`, [basic.stc.static]para.2 says "If a variable with static storage duration has initialization or a destructor with side effects, it shall not be eliminated even if it appears to be unused, ...". This would imply they are guaranteed to be called if they contain side effects.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question right, C++ guarantees the initialization order of variables by order of declaration *within one compilation unit* (i.e. a cpp file). The order of initialization across compilation units is undefined.

In the process of compilation, the `f2_*` functions *according to the standard* would be called, even though functions in `file2.cpp` are not ran. But if the compiler is smart enough, it can omit them entirely if it determines that the resulting program would act *as if it had complied with the standard*. (i.e. if it can guarantee beyond the shadow of the doubt that there would be no difference in behavior between a program with and a program without these functions being called)